# meteor iron router not able to print out property

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

So I have the router

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  console.log("my message");
  console.log(this.request.query.q);
  this.render('map');
});
```

For the url of `http://localhost:3000/?q=somequery`

When I remove the `console.log(this.request.query.q)` it works fine, but adding this line gives the following error:

```
Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'q' of undefined
```

Why is meteor not able to find this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/

If there is a query string or hash fragment in the url, you can access those using the query and hash properties of the this.params object.

```
// given the url: "/post/5?q=s#hashFrag"
Router.route('/post/:_id', function () {
  var id = this.params._id;
  var query = this.params.query;

  // query.q -> "s"
  var hash = this.params.hash; // "hashFrag"
});
```

try

```
this.params.q
```